# Is there a way to see when migrations were ran?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord, rails-migrations, heroku-postgres

In one of our apps db:migrate is not set to automatically run on every deploy to Heroku. It hasn't been Continuously Integrate yet.

We've ran into an issue and for debugging purposes I want to see when a particular migration ran.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Rails does not give such feature, when you run migration, time_stamp of migration is added in an array , to remember which migration is executed and which is not.

so what you can do is , log in to your database (psql if using postgres) and find created time  or updated time of table manually .

this may help you do so https://stackoverflow.com/a/11868687/1970061 .